# sort_by and tap on hash

Tags: ruby, sorting, object, methods

So I'm fairly new to Ruby and coding in general and recently discover `tap` and how it can solve some of my sandwich code. So I'm trying to use `tap` to clean up my method below. As I see my code I realize that the first example looks cleaner, but would still get some help on figuring out why the second example does return the original Array of objects.

```
def sort_arr
  my_var = my_arr.sort_by { |obj| obj.price['usd'] }
  my_var.reverse
end
```

This works and returns a sorted Array of my objects based on the value of the price method. I thought I was able to do this with `tap` but it's returning the original Array

```
def sort_arr
  my_arr.sort_by { |obj| obj.price['usd'] }.tap do |my_obj|
    my_obj.reverse
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tap` will always return the object it was called on (i.e. `x.tap { ... }` is always `x`).

Your method can be simplified to:

```
def sort_arr
  my_arr.sort_by { |obj| obj.price['usd'] }.reverse
end
```

or, if price is numeric,

```
def sort_arr
  my_arr.sort_by { |obj| -obj.price['usd'] }
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Amadan for the explanation and suggestion!

Comment: Also, `x.tap(&:reverse!)` (note the bang) will work here (though `tap` is still absolutely redundant,) thanks to mutating [`Array#reverse!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21). /cc @scarsam

Answer (score 1):

`tap` will always return the object it was called

The primary purpose of this method is to "tap into" a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

You can optimize your code by only using `sort`

```
#For reverse order compare obj2 price with obj1 price
def sort_arr
  my_arr.sort { |obj1, obj2| obj2.price['usd'] <=> obj1.price['usd'] }
end

#For increasing order compare obj1 price with obj2 price
def sort_arr
  my_arr.sort { |obj1, obj2| obj1.price['usd'] <=> obj2.price['usd'] }
end
```

Comment: "You can optimize your code by only using `sort`" - `sort`, in general, uses less *space* than `sort_by`, but more *time* (as it invokes the block `O(n log n)` times, compared to `sort_by` that invokes the block `O(n)` times). For example, my system sorts 100-element array twice as fast using `sort_by`. Most people wouldn't consider using `sort` "optimised", unless you're low on memory.

Comment: Regarding `tap`'s "primary purpose", I suspect its use in debugging is right up there, as one can simply insert, say, `.tap { |e| puts "e=#{e} }` between two chained methods.